# Having trouble with using a while loop for simulating a 1 in 5 chance

Tags: java, random, simulation

I am having trouble with a program that looks to compute the chance of someone winning a contest that they have a 1 in 5 chance of winning. It is a simulation that repeats this 1000 times. The current loop iterates once correctly but just outputs zero to the file for all other loops and I can't figure out why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
public class BottleCapPrize
{
public static void main (String [ ] args) throws IOException
{
    //establishing scanner and variables
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int minimumTrials = 1000;
    int enteredTrials = 0;
    int won = 0;
    int triesToWin = 0;
    double totalTries = 0;
    int winningValue = 0;
    //establishes the number of trials and sais if it is less than 1000
    while(enteredTrials < minimumTrials)
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number of trials greater than 1000: ");
    enteredTrials = in.nextInt();
    if(enteredTrials >= minimumTrials)
    {
        System.out.println("You enetred " + enteredTrials + " trials.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You entered an incorrect number of trials.");
    }
    }
    //establishes file to write to
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("prizeResults.txt"));
    //writes to these files the amount of tries it takes to get the prize 1000 times
    for (int loop = 1; loop <= enteredTrials; loop++)
    {
        while(won != 1)
        {
            winningValue = (int)((Math.random() * 5.0) + 1.0);
            if(winningValue == 1)
            {
                won ++;
                triesToWin ++;
            }
            else
            {
                triesToWin ++;
            }   
        }
        winningValue = 0; 
        outFile.println(triesToWin);
        triesToWin = 0;
    }//end of for loop
    outFile.close ( ); //close the file when finished
    //finds the average number of tries it took
    File fileName = new File("prizeResults.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
    while (inFile.hasNextInt())
    {
        totalTries = totalTries + inFile.nextInt();
    }
    double averageTries = totalTries/enteredTrials;
    //tells the user the average
    System.out.println("You would have to by an average of " + averageTries + " bottles to win.");
}//end of main method
```

}//end of class

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about output the expected output would be an integer greater than one indicating the amount of tries on average it took to roll a one.

Comment: I didn't ask you to clarify the output.  I asked you to clarify what debugging you had done.  As it stands, this question does not appear to show any effort on your part, and is not going to be helpful to future readers.  Please [edit] your question to address these points, and the downvote may be retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting won back to zero. Thus after the first time, when you increment won to 1, the while loop ends, and then in each subsequent for loop, it skips the while loop and prints value of triesToWin which you set back to zero.

Try adding

> won = 0;

after writing to the file.

Comment: Ya I realised this yesterday and forgot to update but you are completely right.